# Business Process Flow disappear in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

I have BPF in case entity (based on the default "phone to case process").
When I'm resolve or cancel the case via C# code - the BPF disappear from the specific case form, and this cause to JS errors in the form.
When I'm resolve or cancel case from CRM - the BPF shown normally.

My code for resolve case:

```
      Entity incidentResolution = new Entity("incidentresolution");
      incidentResolution.Attributes["incidentid"] = new EntityReference("incident", caseID);
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resolution))
      {
        incidentResolution.Attributes["subject"] = resolution;
      }
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
      {
        incidentResolution.Attributes["description"] = description;
      }

      CloseIncidentRequest closeIncidentRequest = new CloseIncidentRequest
      {
        IncidentResolution = incidentResolution,
        Status = new OptionSetValue(1000)
      };

      crmService.Execute(closeIncidentRequest);
```

And this is my code for cancel case:

```
      SetStateRequest setState = new SetStateRequest();
      setState.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference();
      setState.EntityMoniker.Id = caseID;
      setState.EntityMoniker.LogicalName = "incident";
      setState.State = new OptionSetValue(2);
      setState.Status = new OptionSetValue(2000);

      crmService.Execute(setState);
```

Can I do something for the BPF will show in this cases?

Answer (score 0):

Business Process Flow `(BPF)` are managed against a **CRM Entity** by two fields 
`processid` and `stageid`. You have to find the appropriate **stage id and processid** which are placed in the case record by CRM.

To find the **stage id and processid** resolve or cancel case from crm and query in database for these two fields.

So before `Cancelling/Resolving Case` you have to update case.

```
Entity caseEntity = new Entity("incident");
caseEntity.Id=caseID
caseEntity["processid"]= new Guid("ABC") //the processid from DB
caseEntity["stageid"]=new Guid("DEF") //the stageid from DB
crmService.Update(caseEntity);
```